# Flutter - TextField is empty every time I re-open the widget

Tags: flutter, state, textfield

So, I'm new to Flutter and was trying to code a simple notes app to learn my way around it. The layout of the app is a `HomePage` with a ListView of `NoteTile`s that when tapped open a corresponding `NotePage` where you can write down things. The issue I got is that every time I leave the `NotePage` and then re-open it from the `HomePage`, the `NotePage` loses its content.
My first idea was to keep the content in the corresponding `NoteTile` so that when I leave the `NotePage` I would pop with the content, and when needed I would push to the `NotePage` with the previously saved content. The problem is that I didn't find any simple way to push and set the content. I've seen there are Notification and Route methods but they come with quite a lot of boilerplate and they look like it's more for passing data from child to parent, which I can do easily when popping.
So, is there a way to avoid the reset of the content of the `NotePage`? Or maybe is there a simple way to `initState` with the content previously saved?
Here is the code I have so far:

```
class NoteTile extends ListTile {

  final NotePage note;
  final Text title;
  final BuildContext context;

  NoteTile(this.title, this.note, this.context) : super(
    title: title,
    onTap: () => {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => note),
      ),
    },
    onLongPress: () => null,
    );

  void switchToNote() async {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => note),
    );
  }

}
```

`onLongPress` will later be used to delete the note.

```
class NotePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  NotePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NotePageState createState() => _NotePageState();
}

class _NotePageState extends State<NotePage> {
  TextEditingController _controller;
  String _value;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    _controller.addListener(_updateValue);
    _value = '';
  }

  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateValue(){
    _value = _controller.text;
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    Navigator.pop(context, _value);
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title:  Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                hintText: 'New note',
              ),
              maxLines: null,
              controller: _controller,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          ),
        ),
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
    );
  }
}
```

The `_onWillPop` is to send back the content to the `NoteTile`, which currently disregards the return data because I failed to find a way to use that data later when pushing the `NotePage` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListTile` is `StatelessWidget` widget, so you cannot reserve the state, the `NoteTile` should be `StatefulWidget`.

Here is a sample of `NoteTile`:

```dart
class NoteTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Text title;

  const NoteTile({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _NoteTileState();
  }
}

class _NoteTileState extends State<NoteTile> {
  String _result;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _result = "";
  }

  void _onOpenNote() async {
    String result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NotePage(title: _result)),
    );
    if (result != null) {
      _result = result;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: widget.title,
      onTap: _onOpenNote,
    );
  }
}
```

And `NotePage` should be edit in some lines:

`TextEditingController` can have initialize string & have to initialize by `title`:

```dart
_controller = TextEditingController(text: widget.title);
```

`Navigator.pop` can post result and you did it correctly, but if you want to get the result, should wait for `Navigator.of(context).push`, because its run in another thread.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes much more sense now! I would prefer not to use the title field of NotePage to pass the content, but I imagine it is enough to add an additional field in NotePage